# Swashbuckle Schema Filter - How to get property names?

Tags: swashbuckle

I am writing a schema filter for Swashbuckle to implement oneOf/allOf support for properties.  As part of this effort, I need to get the translation of property names from the c# class definition to what is stored in the schema.  Currently, I'm doing a case-insensitive match and then checking for a JsonPropertyName attribute...

```cs
public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
{
    foreach (var prop in context.Type.GetProperties())
    {
        var propName = prop.Name;

        var schemaPropName = schema.Properties.Keys.FirstOrDefault(k => String.Compare(propName, k, true) == 0);
        if (schemaPropName != null)
        {
            propName = schemaPropName;
        }

        var attrJsonName = prop.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyNameAttribute>();
        if (attrJsonName != null)
        {
            var altName = attrJsonName.Name;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(altName))
            {
                propName = altName;
            }
        }

        // etc.
```

but that seem brittle.  For example, what if there is a custom naming convention that inserts underscores in property names?  What if there are other name-changing filters?  etc.

Any ideas on better ways to do this?  Is there some mechanism I can use in either OpenApiSchema or SchemaFilterContext to map c# property names to schema property names?

Comment: Did you ask on GitHub as well?

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution for this?